# Send emails where the box is checked

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to have the possibility to send ID emails using the button "Envoyer ID" only to the rows which are checked: user2, user4 & user5.

Thank you.

[image]

```
 function EnvoiIDCourriel() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Liste").activate();
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var LR = SS.getLastRow()

  var TemplateTexte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  //Permet d'utiliser le corps du courriel qui se trouve dans l'onglet Template


  //Logger.log(NomCandidat);

  //Cette ligne permet de passer à travers de toutes les lignes inscrites
  for (var i = 2;i<=LR;i++){

       var CurrentEmail = SS.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
       var ID = SS.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
       var NomCandidat = SS.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
       var Processus = SS.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
       //var Img = DriveApp.getFileById(1pRBZnWRZcKMFll1OouC8eer2V97e8tT6).getBlob();
       //Logger.log(Img);

       var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
       var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne"

       //Logger.log(ObjetCourriel);

       GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the values are retrieved from Spreadsheet in the for loop. In order to reduce the process cost, in this modification, at first, the values are retrieved from the cells "A2:E", and the email is sent using the retrieved values.
- When the value of checkbox is retrieved by `getValue` and `getValues`, the value type is the boolean type.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var i = 2;i<=LR;i++){

     var CurrentEmail = SS.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
     var ID = SS.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
     var NomCandidat = SS.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
     var Processus = SS.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
     //var Img = DriveApp.getFileById(1pRBZnWRZcKMFll1OouC8eer2V97e8tT6).getBlob();
     //Logger.log(Img);

     var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
     var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne"

     //Logger.log(ObjetCourriel);

     GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage)

  }
```

To:

```
var values = SS.getRange("A2:E" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
values.forEach(([check, NomCandidat, ID, CurrentEmail, Processus]) => {
  if (check === true) {
    var CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.replace("{Nom}",NomCandidat).replace("{ID}",ID).replace("{Processus}",Processus);
    var ObjetCourriel = "Code d'identification: " + ID + " - Test en ligne";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(CurrentEmail, ObjetCourriel, CorpsMessage);
  }
});
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)